# How do i call widgets correctly in PyQt5?

Tags: user-interface, qt-designer, pyqt5

I'm using PyQt5 and Qt Designer to create a UI. After loading the *.ui file I can call widgets in different ways. I have defined two pushButton objects in Qt Designer with the names ButtonBrowse and ButtonDoit.

```
class Dialogo(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui=uic.loadUi("UserInterfaces/QtGUI1_2.ui",self)

        self.ui.ButtonBrowse.clicked.connect(self.load_file)
        self.ButtonDoit.clicked.connect(self.doit)
```

I was wondering why the ButtonDoit is working, since I'm not using the ui between self and the ButtonDoit? Will I get any troubles doing it that way?

I guess the correct way is the one used for ButtonBrowse?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

The second argument of [`uic.loadUi`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/designer.html#PyQt4.uic.loadUi) is optional, and takes an instance of the top-level class from Qt Designer (which is a `QMainWindow` in your example).

If you *don't* use the second argument, a competely new instance of the ui would be created, and the returned object would be of type `QMainWindow`.

If you *do* use it, all the widgets from Qt Designer (apart from the top-level one) will be added to the instance passed in, and the returned object would be of type `Dialogo` (i.e. it will be exactly the same object as the one passed in).

So `self.ui` is redundant in your example, because it will just get set to `self`. All you need to do is this:

```
class Dialogo(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("UserInterfaces/QtGUI1_2.ui", self)
        self.ButtonBrowse.clicked.connect(self.load_file)
        self.ButtonDoit.clicked.connect(self.doit)
```